# How to get past second index on the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am trying to iterate through an image array, displaying each image individually and using a button to move onto the next. However, when the button is clicked it moves onto the next image, but after the second image, it does not move onto the 3rd etc Can anyone find where the loop is getting stuck?

```js
function changeImage() {

  var imageArray = ["/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun2.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun3.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun4.jpg"]
  var currentImage = 0;

  currentImage += 1;
  if (currentImage >= imageArray.length) {
    currentImage = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("mainImage").src = imageArray[currentImage]


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title> App Icons? </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/Website/css/mainstyle.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/rate/js/main.js"></script>
</head>



<body class="body">
  <div>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <div class=topbar>
        <h1> Do you find this App Icon aesthically pleasing</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <div id=displayedImage> </div>
      <img src="/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg" id="mainImage" />

      <div id=answer>
        <label> Strongly Agree </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" required><span>1</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" required><span>2</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" required><span>3</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" required><span>4</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" required><span>5</span></label>
        <label> Strongly disagree</label>
        <hr>


      </div>

      <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value="I am complete">
```

Comment: You've declared `currentImage` as a local variable in the event handler. Every time the event handler is called, the variable will be reinitialized to zero. Move it to *outside* the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, scope. Your `currentImage` should be declared globally because otherwise it will always start at 0. Second, the index of the last element in an array is equal to the array length minus 1, so you need to check `currentImage` against `imageArray.length - 1`:

```js
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {

  var imageArray = ["/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun2.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun3.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun4.jpg"]

  if (currentImage >= imageArray.length - 1) {
    currentImage = 0;
  } else {
    currentImage += 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("mainImage").src = imageArray[currentImage]
  console.log(currentImage);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <div class=topbar>
      <h1> Do you find this App Icon aesthically pleasing</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div id=displayedImage> </div>
    <img src="/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg" id="mainImage" />

    <div id=answer>
      <label> Strongly Agree </label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" required><span>1</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" required><span>2</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" required><span>3</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" required><span>4</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" required><span>5</span></label>
      <label> Strongly disagree</label>
      <hr>


    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value="I am complete">
```

Comment: Glad to help ya!

Comment: Why doesn't answer reflect the changed variable scope described in text?

Comment: The range check is wrong. The original is correct in that regard, this version will not display the last image.

Comment: yes, it never seems to reach the last image in the array?

Comment: It does reach. I've added a `console.log()` line to show that.